# security patch 5944 - error

Tags: security, ce-1.8.1.0, patches, supee-5994

our [site was hacked](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128451/strange-things-displaying-in-site-and-music-is-playing) recently. we had backup , so we reverted and restricted site only to our ip , now we are trying to install all security patches. we installed **7405 , 5344 , 6482**  patches. we cross  checked it by below code in **applied.patch.list**

```
2016-08-03 19:22:57 UTC | SUPEE-7405 | CE_1.8.1.0 | v1.1 | 7abc9e2aeabfd6fe2adb9ec5aeaa1338e3100178 | Fri Feb 5 13:26:33 2016 +0200 | 7b9c8a8353510903624d8d9ce11b982811dd0df5..7abc9e2aeabfd6fe2adb9ec5aeaa1338e3100178
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php


2016-08-03 19:49:41 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 537 (offset -4 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php


2016-08-03 19:55:03 UTC | SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.9.2.0 | v1 |  | Tue Jul 14 14:17:04 2015 +0300 |
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 209 (offset -24 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php
```

now 5994 , 6788 , 6285 patches are left.

Now when we include below code in patch.php file and ran in browser , we got below errror.

**patch.php**

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1-2015-05-15-04-34-46.sh");
print("</PRE>");
echo "Done";
?>
```

**error :**

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
patching file get.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
The next patch would create the file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Done
```

Comment: i replaced above files which are giving error by original files  as present here : https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patches have to be applied in the right order, starting with the lowest number, otherwise they fail as soon as they modify the same files.

So after you restored the original files, you should apply the patches in the following order:

- APPSEC-212
- SUPEE-1533
- SUPEE-3762
- SUPEE-5344
- SUPEE-5994
- SUPEE-6285
- SUPEE-6482
- SUPEE-6788
- SUPEE-7405
- SUPEE-7405 v1.1

See also: [Magento 1.8.1.0 Patches](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99904/magento-1-8-1-0-patches)